# I have searched, but considering that I am ignorant, I cannot implement. Will someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Tags: java

So, I have already figured out how to calculate the average and number of integers entered; however, I cannot seem to figure out how to figure out the largest, smallest, even and odd numbers. I have tried several things, but it does not work.

Any tips or suggestions? I do not need for you to write anything for me, but a little guidance would be appreciated. (this is for school, do not want to cheat, just need some help).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab4
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {


    double large = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    double small = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    double evenCount = 0;
    double oddCount = 0;
    double foot = 0;
    double ball = 0;
    double eagles = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter positive or negative integers -- enter zero to quit");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean philly = false;

    while (!philly)
    {
        eagles = scan.nextDouble();
        if (eagles == 0)
        {
            philly = true;
        }
        else
        {
            foot = foot + eagles;
            ball++;
        }
    }

    if (eagles%2==0)
    {
        evenCount++;
        System.out.println("The number of even integers is: " + evenCount);

    if (eagles%2==1)
    oddCount++;
        System.out.println("The number of odd integers is: " + oddCount);

    if (eagles < small)
        small = eagles;
    System.out.println("The smallest integer entered is: " + small);

    if (eagles > large)
        large = eagles;
        System.out.println("The largest integer entered is: " + large);

    if (ball > 0)

        System.out.println("The number of integers entered is: " + ball);
        double avg = foot / ball;
        System.out.println("Average of integers: " + avg);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("No data");
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: swap these values around `double large = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        double small = Integer.MIN_VALUE;`  cos nothing will be larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and nothing will be smaller than `Integer.MIN_VALUE`

Comment: Please improve your question title. It should summarize your actual coding problem, not your tail of woe.

Comment: In other words, it should be informative and key us in immediately to what you're asking, not be a "woe is me" sort of thing.

Comment: First thing you should do is verify those `{}`s are right.

Comment: Also try using a debugger, so that you can see what is actually happening

Comment: Declare `eagles` where it is assigned, and the compiler will tell you why it's not working: `double eagles = scan.nextDouble();`

Answer (score 0):

Some tips:

1)
Make all variables of type `Integer`. You cannot determine odd/even from `Double` values.

2)
Initialize the `large` with `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `small` with `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

3)
The check for odd/even/smaller/greater should be executed within the `while` loop.